# Capture event of pressing refresh icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a way to capture the event of clicking refresh icon?

For pressing F5 I use `keydown()`

I do not use `onbeforeunload` because it is called at the closing and crossing between pages.

Answer (score 2):

there's no `refresh` event, but there's `beforeunload` event which may fit.

try:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    alert('about to unload page');
});
```

i know it doesn't answer your exact question, but it's the closest you'll get...

the browsers' next location (new page on this website, other website, or same page) is not accessible, and for good reasons. you don't want a website to know where you're navigating next.

hope that helps.

Comment: I do not use onbeforeunload because it is called at the closing and crossing between pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onunload = function(e) {
    // Firefox || IE
    e = e || window.event;

    var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;

    if(y < 0)  
        alert("Window closed");
    else 
        alert("Window refreshed");
}
```

Copied from http://forums.asp.net/t/1829278.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also think outside the box. For example things like SESSION to save the amount of refreshing and within a specific amount of sesonds. Say like a person pressing F5 will reload the page. We do the following:

Start counting every second using (interval) and saving our (session) using (ajax). So every second our session will be updated in PHP. Then we make a condition in PHP that if our session has passed 2seconds or with other words hasn't been updated for 2sec, yet if it has been updated within 3sec to 5sec, then a page has just been refreshed. Now that doesn't mean F5 has been pressed, but an expected result of F5 has been initiated within 3->5sec. You choose of course how long time you want to wait and where and how complicated the script you wanna make.